# Hadoop - Pseudo-Distributed Operation

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to copy a file quangle.txt from my localsystem to Hadoop using the command below:

```
testuser@ubuntu:~/Downloads/hadoop/bin$ ./hadoop fs -copyFromLocal Desktop/quangle.txt hdfs://localhost/testuser/quangle.txt

13/11/28 06:35:50 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:51 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:52 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:53 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
13/11/28 06:35:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
copyFromLocal: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I tried to ping 127.0.0.1 and I got the response. Please advice

Answer (score 3):

just add correct port to the filepath after localhost:

```
hdfs://localhost:9000/testuser/quangle.txt
```

Comment: Where are you getting port 9000 from?

Comment: Hi Dan, as far as I am aware the 2 default ports for hdfs may be 8020 or 9000. If the 8020 doesn't work I'd try the 9000. See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation for more info.

Comment: 9000 is from the core-site.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your Name node isn't running - try running the `jps` cmd and see if `NameNode` is listed in the running services (or you might have to run `ps axww | grep NameNode` if the NameNode was started by/under a different user)

Does `sudo netstat -atnp | grep 8020` yield any results?

If the Name Node is refusing to start then copy in your Name Node logs into to your original question (or post a new question - after searching for the error first of all to see if someone else has had this problem)

Answer (score 1):

Try running `jps` to see the currently running Java processes.

Are all Hadoop processes running, especially the Namemode?

If yes, you should get this output (with different process ids):

```
10015 JobTracker
9670 TaskTracker
9485 DataNode
10380 Jps
9574 SecondaryNameNode
9843 NameNode
```

Comment: testuser@ubuntu:~/Downloads/hadoop/bin$ jps
6230 DataNode
6913 Jps
6376 SecondaryNameNode
6084 NameNode
6478 JobTracker
6626 TaskTracker
testuser@ubuntu:~

Comment: Ok, so your namenode is up. Can you check if you have done everything specified by (http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) Hadoop installation guide? Or is this the one you have been following already?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `hadoop fs -put ~/Desktop/quangle.txt /testuser`, after copied, you can look up it via `hadoop fs -ls /testuser` in the /testuser directory

Answer (score 0):

you create Desktop and others with the command `hadoop fs -mkdir testuser` and then try, it worked for me that way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something wrong with your setting for Pseudodistributed Mode.
It should be configured in this order:

1. fill up the configuration files:core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml,
   mapred-site.xml, yar-site.xml.
2. Configuring SSH
3. Formatting the
   HDFS filesystem
4. Starting and stopping the daemons