# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused when trying to access a file from HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am writing a simple standalone program using the scala API for Apache-spark. I need to access a file from HDFS. Simple commands from the shell like hadoop fs -ls work fine. however, when i try to access the file from within my program, I get the following error at runtime :

I have been googling the errors for a few hours but can't figure out what the problem is. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

```
14/06/25 10:48:27 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
14/06/25 10:48:28 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://spark@us-col-svb-0063.dunnhumby.co.uk:48183]
14/06/25 10:48:28 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://spark@us-col-svb-0063.dunnhumby.co.uk:48183]
14/06/25 10:48:30 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/06/25 10:48:30 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
[error] (run-main-0) java.net.ConnectException: Call to USHADOOP/10.152.84.251:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Call to USHADOOP/10.152.84.251:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1075)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:898)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:726)
        at MovieRecExp$.main(experiment.scala:30)
        at MovieRecExp.main(experiment.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:434)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:560)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1050)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:898)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:726)
        at MovieRecExp$.main(experiment.scala:30)
        at MovieRecExp.main(experiment.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 16 s, completed Jun 25, 2014 10:48:40 AM
```

Comment: That's a security exception. Is your spark bound to a routable  network from your HDFS host? Can its IP Address be resolved to a valid hostname? HDFS is picky with that.

Answer (score 0):

it is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256124/hadoop-pseudo-distributed-operation). If you are trying load any file from HDFS, make sure you specify the correct port in the file path, eg. hdfs://localhost:9000/testpath/file.txt